# How can i create two sections to focus and other to writting?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

This code i am using to focus of a entry, its a custon entry

```cs
protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);

    if (e.PropertyName == Entry.IsFocusedProperty.PropertyName )
    {
        //place1. this code is use to focus
    }

    // place2. here enter the text when the user written
}
```

How can i know if the user is writting? but dont enter to both places.

Comment: @Jason help me please

Comment: can you post your custom control ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Option 1**:You could set the TextProperty to check the user editing .

```
protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);

    if (e.PropertyName == Entry.IsFocusedProperty.PropertyName)
    {
        //place1. this code is use to focus
    }

    if (e.PropertyName == Entry.TextProperty.PropertyName)
    {
        //place2. this code is use to edit 

        var content = Element.Text;
    }
}
```

**Option 2:**

You could set the **TextChanged** of the Entry .

```
protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Entry> e)
{
    base.OnElementChanged(e);

    if(Control!=null)
    {
        Element.TextChanged += Element_TextChanged;
    }

}

private void Element_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // var content = Element.Text;
}
```

Comment: You could define them in the constructor or in the method `OnElementChanged` .

Comment: If you want to get more event of entry you could check the source code of the element .

Comment: @asdww You’ve already assigned the bounty and marked this question as Answered

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT help me please with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60778529/change-of-color-de-my-custom-enter-once-is-clicked-my-button