# How get the value of a BindableProperty?

Tags: xamarin.forms

I want get the value of a BindableProperty, because i want that have my BindableProperty two states for i can differentiate

```
<local:MyEntry event="{Binding Flag,  Mode=TwoWay}">
```

and in my custom entry:

```
    public static  BindableProperty EventProperty =
                BindableProperty.Create("event", typeof(string), typeof(MyEntry), "sigle", propertyChanged: (obj, oldValue, newValue) =>
                { });
private string flag;
        public  string Flag
        {
            get { return flag; }
            set
            {
                if (flag != value)
                {
                    flag = value;
                    NotifyPropertyChanged("event");
                }
            }
        }
```

and in my viewModel, this is the code:

```
private string flag;
        public string Flag
        {
            get { return flag; }
            set
            {
                if (flag != value)
                {
                    flag = value;
                    RaisePropertyChanged(() => Flag);
                }
            }
        }
private async Task Execute()
        {
            Flag = "Change";
        }
```

in my custom renderer

```
protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);
                Console.WriteLine("HERE "+ (entry as MyEntry).Flag); 
//here i want to get the value
```

**with help of answer**

```
if (e.PropertyName == MyEntry.EventProperty.PropertyName)
            {
                var entry = Element as MyEntry;
                var Flag = entry.Flag;
                Console.WriteLine("... "+ Flag);
```

Comment: @Lucas Zhang-MSFT help me please!!!

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT excuse me!!!, i edited my question

Comment: Did you bind the flag to event?

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT from my xaml? what file do you need to see?

Comment: Of course you could post the full code , which will be helpful to solve the issue .

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT i edited my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### in Custom Renderer

```
 public static BindableProperty FlagProperty = BindableProperty.Create("Flag", typeof(string), typeof(MyEntry), string.Empty, propertyChanged: (obj, oldValue, newValue) =>
        {
            var entry = obj as MyEntry;
            entry.Flag = newValue.ToString();
        });
private string flag;
public  string Flag
{
   get { return flag; }
   set
   {
      if (flag != value)
      {
         flag = value;
         NotifyPropertyChanged("Flag");
      }
   }
}
```

#### in Custom Renderer

```
protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
   base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);

   if (e.PropertyName == MyEntry.EventProperty.PropertyName)
   {
       //  will been invoked when the value changed
       var entry = Element as MyEntry;
       var Flag = entry.Flag;
   }


}
```

Comment: i cannot see the flag in a console  var Flag = entry.Flag; Console.WriteLine("... "+ Flag);

Comment: It will been called when you change the value in view model .

Comment: yeah, but i only can see the three points of the console, Console.WriteLine("... " why?

Comment: never enter here public  string Flag
        {get { return flag; }
            set
            {
                if (flag != value)
                {

Comment: thanks!!! but when i put var entry = obj as MyEntry;
            entry.Flag = newValue.ToString();    i get this wrong Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210201/discussion-between-mikkylekyle-and-lucas-zhang-msft).

Comment: can you help me please with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61113556/how-can-i-capture-the-back-button-click